# Dropdown Menu on WordPress runs only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

The site on WordPress with a lot of jquery js and such menu script:

```
function mainmenu() {
    $(" #navigation .menu ul ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix

    $(" #navigation .menu li").hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(400);
    },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){                   
    mainmenu();
});
```

when loaded with WooCommerce plugin didn't show dropdown menu.

I started changing jquery versions on site from 1.3.2 and finished with 1.8.3 - the dropdown menu works now but only once (I mean drop down on hover). Please help to make it work as intended. Thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you may look at debug console of a browser. press Ctrl+Shift+I and watch when mouse out event happens, a log console must show an error

Comment: I don't see anything there that would cause an issue with jQuery 1.8.x. Chances are there's something in your WP theme or another plugin that's using a deprecated method and causing trouble. Take Banzay's advice and check the console (F12 on Windows, console tab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No HTML provided, but all of the code above can be reduced to the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#navigation .menu li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').show();
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').hide();
    })
});
```

(notice the first line uses `jQuery`, instead of `$` in order to properly work with WordPress' noconflict, I've no idea how it works the first time 'though)

If that doesn't help, please provide some markup to get a better idea of the issue and check your console as already suggested.